# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to \Entity\Image::setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile,

Tags: php, symfony

**I Got this error**

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to swaam\ImageUploaderBundle\Entity\Image::setFile()
 must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile,

instance of swaam\ImageUploaderBundle\Entity\Image given, called in D:\xamp\htdocs\shams\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php 
on line 438 and defined in D:\xamp\htdocs\shams\src\swaam\ImageUploaderBundle\Entity\Image.php line 166

according to the mention line no 166 its the function setFile() here is my function

```
 public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (isset($this->path)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->temp = $this->path;
        $this->path = null;
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}
```

I couldn't even understand the error , any one please help me and explain a bit the reason of the error plus the possible solution.

Comment: What is the argument for `SetFile()` when it's called?

Comment: It's saying you're passing the wrong kind of object as parameter when calling the function!

Comment: argument to setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)

Comment: but the same function is working fine with a simple form, i am trying to create admin side of same entity. if same thing is working for a simple form, it should be working on admin side... i guess

Comment: @deceze what can be the right parameter then ? any idea?

Comment: You must pass an object of type `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`.

Comment: use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile

Answer (score 4):

I've got a similar error message. I solved it by adding `<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>` to my form tag.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using `choice` field type in a form for a field that represented an entity.

To fix this I changed `choice` to `entity` in `buildForm` and also added class that this entity is supposed to resolve to to options, so `add` statement started to look as following:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
                  'product', 
                  'entity', 
                  [
                      'class' => 'Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Product',
                  ]
    );
 }
```